# Fixing decorators arguments

Tags: python, decorator, functools

I have the following third party decorator:

```
def retry(exception_to_check, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2, logger=None):
```

I would like to make another decorator, `@my_retry`, that is similar to `@retry`, but with fixed arguments.

I've tried doing it using `functools.partial`:

```
my_retry = partial(retry, RETRY_EXCEPTIONS, tries=5, delay=5, backoff=3, logger=logging)
```

But when I use the new decorator I get the following exception:

```
TypeError: retry() got multiple values for keyword argument 'tries'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to make a wrapper around `retry`, like this

```
def my_retry(retry_exceptions, tries=5, delay=5, backoff=3, logger=logging):
    return retry(retry_exceptions, tries, delay, backoff, logger)
```

and use `@my_retry()`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it works, except that I have to use `@my_retry()`.

Comment: @Tzach Yeah, we wrapped the functionality of `retry` with our custom function... :(

Comment: That's fine by me, please update the answer and I will accept.